# dist2Line - Error in dist2Line(...) could not find the function "dist2Line"

Tags: r, line, distance, distance-matrix

I have a csv file with points (about 20 millions georeferenced points) and a line shapefile. I want to find for each point the closest distance to the line. The line is not a straight line it's actually a border between 2 countries.
I am trying to use dist2Line function but I get the following error message : Error in dist2Line(points,line,distfun=distHaversine) : could not find the function "dist2Line"

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

points <- read.csv(file = "~path/points.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    line <- reagOGR(file="~path/","line")
    d <- dist2Line(points, line, distfun=distHaversine)
```

Does anyone ever met this issue? Is there an alternative way to compute the closest distance matrix from each point to the line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code none of used packages have this function. That is why R can't find it.

```
Error in dist2Line(points,line,distfun=distHaversine) : could not find the function "dist2Line"
```

Probably you want use `dist2Line` from package [geosphere](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geosphere/versions/1.5-5/topics/dist2Line). Sou you have to install it and load it.

```
install.packages("geosphere")
library(geosphere)
```